# BSON produced by mongoexport from Mongodb is not a valid JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, gson, mongoexport

I am new to Mongo and trying to export a JSON file from a collection.
The `> MONGOEXPORT` worked well and created a JSON file.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54c8f3fb5e24e03c473243c4" }, "username" : "Aman", "password" : "yesboss" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54c901c1953b434dabadbabf" }, "username" : "AMAN2" }
```

Now, JSONLint shows me the error that it is not a valid JSON.

**I need this to import in my Java Project to extract values from it.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoExport exports valid JSON. Your Java should parse each line, instead of the whole file, as a JSON object.

If you want to treat the entire export file as a JSON object, then use the option `--jsonArray`

```
--jsonArray
output to a json array rather than one 
object per line
```

#### Example:

```
mongoexport --db test -c x
connected to: 127.0.0.1
{ "_id" : "54c8f3fb5e24e03c473243c4", "username" : "Aman", "password" : "yesboss" }
{ "_id" : "54c901c1953b434dabadbabf", "username" : "AMAN2" }
exported 2 records

mongoexport --db test -c x --jsonArray
connected to: 127.0.0.1
[{ "_id" : "54c8f3fb5e24e03c473243c4", "username" : "Aman", "password" : "yesboss" },{ "_id" : "54c901c1953b434dabadbabf", "username" : "AMAN2" }]
exported 2 records
```